# On Windows, how to restrict access to a folder, sub folder and files by only some applications (not users)

Tags: windows, filesystems, access-control, win32-process

We have an application which is not per user and can be used my multiple users simultaneously and data is also shared by all users. So the path we use data folders is ProgramData\OurAppName\Data (post Vista) and give full control to all users, so that our application run by them can make changes to files under Data folder.

Now the issue, with this, any other application (malware/virus) can also modify files i.e. an attack can be made on our application's data files. Our applications is Win32 Desktop application.

Is there anyway by which we can restrict the access to Data folder to only our applications?

Comment: Malware will of course run with one of those user's account.  So rather pointless to try to stop it that way.  The real attacks you have to worry about is one user destroying the data of another.  Without any backup.  Usually resolved quickly after this happened once by the admin changing the storage location to a file share.  Make sure he can.

Comment: I could not understand the solution. Can you elaborate? Genuine users running our application to access the same data directory is not any issue, as applications handle the multi-user scenario. Is there anyway by which we can restrict the access to Data folder to only our applications? as we want to restrict access by other applications.

Comment: Yes, a filesystem filter driver lets you restrict file access to only some applications (processes) and deny access from other applications. This is not an absolute solution, because malware can work in kernel mode or otherwise bypass such checks, but the change of accessing the data files is lowered significantly with this approach.

Comment: Malware can brute force your admin account and get elevated permissions to write to any folder without any restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows security model is per-user, not per-application.  So there is no built-in way to restrict access to files based on which application is making the request.

The proper solution is for a server program (either running on an actual server, or as a system service on the local machine) to have exclusive access to the files (which works because the server program will be running as a different user) and for the client application (the application the end users run) to make all requests via the server.  The server can then vet the requests to make sure they are not destructive before carrying them out.

Possible ad-hoc solutions would include a system service that hands out access to the files to your application (via handle duplication) or a file system filter driver.  These approaches could be bypassed easily enough, but might be adequate against common-variety viruses that are not targeting your application specifically.